# Tuple of tuples to Dict of dicts using Dict Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am executing the following sqlite command:

```
c.execute("SELECT surname,forename,count(*) from census_data group by surname, forename")
```

so that c.fetchall() is as follows:

```
(('Griffin','John', 7), 
 ('Griffin','James', 23), 
 ('Griffin','Mary',30), 
 ('Griffith', 'John', 4),
 ('Griffith','Catherine', 5)
)
```

Is it possible to construct a dict of the following form using a dict comprehension:

```
{'Griffin': {'John': 7, 'James': 23, 'Mary':30}, 'Griffith': {'John':4,'Catherine':5}}
```

this is as far as I got:

```
counts = {s:(f,c) for s,f,c in c.fetchall()}
```

which overwrites values. Im using python 3.

Comment: Shouldn't `c.fetchall()` return a list not a tuple? [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create the inner dicts automatically when needed:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = (('Griffin','John', 7), 
 ('Griffin','James', 23), 
 ('Griffin','Mary',30), 
 ('Griffith', 'John', 4),
 ('Griffith','Catherine', 5)
)

out = defaultdict(dict)
for (name, first, value) in data:
    out[name][first] = value


# {'Griffin': {'John': 7, 'James': 23, 'Mary': 30}, 'Griffith': {'John': 4, 'Catherine': 5}}
```

Comment: using Dict Comprehension?

Comment: @Frank It's a better solution than dictcomp. You can't do everything with comprehensions.

Comment: I agree 100% but the task was to use a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

Coming with *dict comprehension* though with `itertools.groupby` magic:

```
from itertools import groupby

counts = {k: dict(_[1:] for _ in g) for k, g in groupby(c.fetchall(), key=lambda t: t[0])}
print(counts)
```

The output:

```
{'Griffin': {'John': 7, 'James': 23, 'Mary': 30}, 'Griffith': {'John': 4, 'Catherine': 5}}
```

Comment: Can you describe your solution a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with something like this.

```py
my_query = (('Griffin','John', 7), ('Griffin','James', 23), ('Griffin','Mary',30), ('Griffith', 'John', 4), ('Griffith','Catherine', 5) )

dict_query = {}
for key1, key2, value in my_query:
    if key1 not in dict_query:
        dict_query[key1] = {}
    dict_query[key1][key2] = value
```

Edit1

More elegant.

```py
from collections import defaultdict 
dict_query = defaultdict(dict) 
for key1, key2, value in my_query:
    dict_query[key1][key2] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `defaultdict` you can use the dictionary method `setdefault()`:

```
dct = {}

for k1, k2, v2 in c.fetchall():
    v1 = dct.setdefault(k1, {})
    v1[k2] = v2
```

or

```
for k1, k2, v2 in c.fetchall():
    dct.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = v2
```

Result:

```
{'Griffin': {'John': 7, 'James': 23, 'Mary': 30},
 'Griffith': {'John': 4, 'Catherine': 5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it holding on `itertools.groupby` and `functools.itemgetter`.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

result = { name: dict(v for _, v in values) for name, values in groupby(((x[0], x[1:]) for x in c.fetchall()), itemgetter(0))}
print(result)
# {'Griffin': {'John': 7, 'James': 23, 'Mary': 30}, 'Griffith': {'John': 4, 'Catherine': 5}}
```

The outer loop splits the data between name and its values, that then `groupby(...)` collapses by name. The inner loop simply builds a dict with the corresponding values.

Comment: `{name: dict(map(itemgetter(1, 2), values)) for name, values in groupby(data, itemgetter(0))}`